# Extract nodes from json based on user input

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, glom

I need to extract object from the given json based on the node chain passed by user and neglect those which are not in
user input, then create a new json object

my master json is :

```
{
    "menustructure": 
    [
            {
             "node":"Admin",
             "path":"admin",
                "child":[
                        {
                            "node": "Admin.resouce1",
                            "path":"resouce1",
                            "rank":1
                         },
                    
                        {"node":"Admin.resouce2",
                            "path": "oath",
                            "rank":2
                        }
                       ]
            },
            {
                "node":"Workspace",
                "path": "wsp",
                "child":[{
                        "node": "Workspace.system1",
                        "path":"sys1"
                    
                    },
                    {
                        "node": "Workspace.system2",
                        "path":"sys2"
                    }
                ]
            }

        
    ]
}
```

for example if user pass `['Admin.resource1', 'Workspace']` so expeceted ouput json will be
**Note**    '.' in element of user inputted list means that node have child nodes and new json will be having all those child node details including parent node details.

```
{
    "menustructure": 
    [
            {
             "node":"Admin",
             "path":"admin",
                "child":[
                        {
                            "node": "Admin.resouce1",
                            "path":"resouce1",
                            "rank":1
                         }
                       ]
            },
            {
                "node":"Workspace",
                "path": "wsp",
                "child":[{
                        "node": "Workspace.system1",
                        "path":"sys1"
                    
                    },
                    {
                        "node": "Workspace.system2",
                        "path":"sys2"
                    }
                ]
            }

        
    ]
}
```

or another example is : `['Admin.resouce2', 'workspace.system1']` then expected json will be:

```
{
    "menustructure": 
    [
            {
             "node":"Admin",
             "path":"admin",
                "child":[
                        
                        {"node":"Admin.resouce2",
                            "path": "oath",
                            "rank":2
                        }
                       ]
            },
            {
                "node":"Workspace",
                "path": "wsp",
                "child":[{
                        "node": "Workspace.system1",
                        "path":"sys1"
                    
                    }
                ]
            }
    ]
}
```

or if only single node passed `['Admin']` then output json will be:

```
{
    "menustructure": 
    [
            {
             "node":"Admin",
             "path":"admin",
                "child":[
                        {
                            "node": "Admin.resouce1",
                            "path":"resouce1",
                            "rank":1
                         },
                    
                        {"node":"Admin.resouce2",
                            "path": "oath",
                            "rank":2
                        }
                       ]
            }   
    ]
}
```

Any Help will be great.

Code I tried is:

```
master = json.loads(m)
menustruct = []
nde = ['Admin.resouce1', 'Workspace']
test_master = master['menustructure']
temp_json = test_master
print()

for n in nde:
    temp_data = None
    if "." in n:
        menu_series = n.split(".")
    for m in temp_json:
        temp_data = m
        if temp_data['node'] == menu_series[0]:
            for sub_child in temp_data['child']:
                if sub_child['id'] == menu_series[1]:
                    idx = temp_data['child'].index(sub_child)
                else:
                    temp_data['child'].remove(sub_child)
                #if menu_iter.has_next()
        menustruct.append(temp_data)

print(menustruct)
```

but its not working as intended problem that I'm facing with this code is
if user pass `['Admin.resouce1', 'Admin.resouce2', 'Workspace']` then no data is appended in Admin child and Workspace is getting loaded twice

```
[{'node': 'Admin', 'path': 'admin', 'child': []}, {'node': 'Workspace', 'path': 'wsp', 'child': [{'node': 'Workspace.system1', 'path': 'sys1'}, {'node': 'Workspace.system2', 'path': 'sys2'}]}, {'node': 'Admin', 'path': 'admin', 'child': []}, {'node': 'Workspace', 'path': 'wsp', 'child': [{'node': 'Workspace.system1', 'path': 'sys1'}, {'node': 'Workspace.system2', 'path': 'sys2'}]}, {'node': 'Admin', 'path': 'admin', 'child': []}, {'node': 'Workspace', 'path': 'wsp', 'child': [{'node': 'Workspace.system1', 'path': 'sys1'}, {'node': 'Workspace.system2', 'path': 'sys2'}]}]
```

And also this code is not ideal if there are sub-child of child.

Comment: You haven't shown us the code you've written so far. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @J_H I have updated my question with the code I tried.

Answer (score 1):

[Glom](https://glom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) addresses exactly this problem.

Comment: I went through the documentation of Glom as I understand Glom will work if I have key node to all dictionaries for example in my case  'Admin': {
             "node":"Admin",
             "path":"admin",
                "child":[
                        'resouce0':{
                            "id": "resouce1",
                            "node": "Admin.resouce1",
                            "path":"resouce0",
                            "rank":0
                         },
which is not a case in my json , please suggest If I misunderstand something